# Can you steam eggs with other food? Is this healthy?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, steaming

I cooked eggs on top of potatoes and I was wondering if this was a wrong thing to do.

Edit: it isn't duplicate, it is about steaming not boiling.

Comment: If you're asking about *food safety*, then yes, it is perfectly safe to do so. If you're asking any other "health" question, we don't answer those here.

Comment: As Ester implicitly asked, is your question about food safety, or something else (i.e. nutrition)?

Comment: It is about salmonella, so it is about food safety afaik.

Comment: Hi demonoga, the concept that is important here is called "cross-contamination". As soon as you have your eggs and other food in the same pot, the same food safety rules will apply. It doesn't matter if you steam or boil or do something else. That's why, when you want to know about the food safety aspect, the two questions are duplicates - you have created the same situation, from the perspective of food safety. The taste of the final product might be different, but that's not important in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for others if steaming and boiling are very similar in that sense to combine threads as this being duplicate. It is just that I have seen the duplicate question before and was sure it was different.